# Select MAX() causes error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a T-SQL query that will return the highest salary from the `job_positions` table and the name of the person(s) who has it.

So far, my solution is:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(e.salary) AS [Max salary]
    , p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname AS [THE LUCKY MAN]
FROM 
    persons p 
JOIN 
    job_positions e ON (p.id_person = e.id_person)
```

But this produces the error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
>   Column 'persons.firstname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
>   Column 'persons.lastname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

However, it only seems to be self-explanatory; The problem is probably with the `MAX` function. After deleting it, the result is full name-salary table. I wonder why it cannot just extract the maximum row...

Comment: well, the message is telling you what the error is. You are using `MAX`, but you have another column that you don't have on an aggregate function nor you are using it on the `GROUP BY`. Add `GROUP BY p.firstname+' '+p.lastname` at the end of your query

Comment: @Lamak The same thing as with herbae's answer-"Doesn't work- the result is the same as if they were no "MAX" function(full salary-name table)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **only one** employee who can get `Max salary` then try this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.salary                       AS [Max salary],
             p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname AS [THE LUCKY MAN]
FROM   persons p
       JOIN job_positions e
         ON ( p.id_person = e.id_person )
ORDER  BY e.salary DESC
```

If **more than one** is getting Max salary then use `Window Function` with `Dense_Rank` to find all the names.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Dense_rank()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY e.salary)         Rn,
                e.salary                       AS [Max salary],
                p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname AS [THE LUCKY MAN]
         FROM   persons p
                JOIN job_positions e
                  ON ( p.id_person = e.id_person ))
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  Rn = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES e.salary                       AS [Max salary],
             p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname AS [THE LUCKY MAN]
FROM   persons p
       JOIN job_positions e
         ON ( p.id_person = e.id_person )
ORDER  BY e.salary DESC
```

Comment: You can also just use the `with ties` keyword if you want duplicates:  `select top 1 with ties . . .`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks Gordan good to know about this. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(e.salary) AS [Max salary],
p.firstname+' '+p.lastname AS [THE LUCKY MAN]
FROM persons p JOIN job_positions e ON (p.id_person = e.id_person)
GROUP BY p.firstname, p.lastname -- group by clause needed
```

Comment: while this is right, you should also explain what the problem was to make this a good answer

Comment: @pquest Actually this probably isn't right as it will give the max salary per person where I suspect the OP wants the overall person with the largest salary.

Comment: @DavidG ah yeah, looking again, I think you are probably right. That being said, the other part of my comment, which was the important part, still stands.

Comment: @pquest Absolutely, an answer is no good without an explanation.

Comment: T sql does not support this syntax combining aggregated and non aggregated expressions in select query

Comment: Doesn't work- the result is the same as if they were no "MAX" function(full salary-name table).

Comment: You're both right... I just tried to solve the error.  It's possible to infer from "THE LUCKY MAN" that the guy wants the biggest salary in the whole company.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution that isn't totally ugly:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(e.salary) AS [Max salary]
    , p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname AS [THE LUCKY MAN]
FROM 
    persons p 
JOIN 
    job_positions e ON (p.id_person=e.id_person)
WHERE
    e.salary=(SELECT max(e.salary) FROM e.job_positions)
```

But I still wonder why isn't it possible to just use "MAX" with select with "join".